# I'm trying to make a share command for my economy bot, but it won't let me format my command how I want it

Tags: discord.py

So I'm trying to make a share coins command, and I want to format it like this:
!share [amount of coins] [member]
This is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def share(ctx, amount = None, member:discord.Member):
```

But it gives me this error:

```
  File "main.py", line 379
    async def share(ctx, amount = None, member:discord.Member):
                    ^
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance

Nevermind I figured it out. I just had to remove the = None.

Comment: please close this question

Comment: uhhh idk how XD

Comment: it should be one of the grey buttons on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

First of all, did you put any code under that, secondly if it's in a cog, you have to put self, ctx, etc.